# How do I define a database index in HoboFields?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, hobo

With [HoboFields](http://cookbook.hobocentral.net/manual/hobofields), I can declare fields for my model in its own file, like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  fields do
    login :string
    persistence_token :string
  end

end
```

I'd like to know if there's equivalent syntax for the `add_index` command I can use in vanilla Rails migrations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base 

  fields do 
    login :string 
    persistence_token :string, :index => true
  end 

end
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't exist yet in HoboFields, but I've suggested it on [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/hobousers/browse_thread/thread/c3b2247407647a19) and it seems it's going to be implemented in a future release.

Edit: it's been implemented and is currently in this experimental branch: http://github.com/tablatom/hobo/tree/indexgen. I'll update the answer when it gets included in a release.